# How can I get Ethernet adapter and still be able to charge my tablet

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, charging, lan

I found this adapter to add Ethernet to my android phone, but looks like doesnt power the device. Is there a way to have Ethernet connection and still be able to charge the device at the same time?

[image]

Also found this [**one**](https://amzn.to/2VFGfQm) but said power is for the USB devices and wont charge the tablet.

[image]

Comment: halo @Juan, did you happen to find the solution?

Comment: I didnt found a solution, So had to settle with wifi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I have not found a single device solution that solves the problem. Utilizing multiple devices can solve the problem.

According to [PoE Texas](https://www.poetexas.com/blogs/news/android-tablet-power-and-data-with-power-over-ethernet), you can combine the use of a USB to RJ45, Powered USB OTG Hub, PoE Splitter Micro-USB and RJ45. Finding a 10 Watt OTG Hub would be good for continuous use of a charging device.